# Repartition does not affect number of tasks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How do I increase the number of tasks in order to reduce the amount of memory per task needed?

The following very simple example fails:

```py
df = (
    spark
    .read
    .format('delta')
    .load(input_path)
)
df = df.orderBy("contigName", "start", "end")

# write ordered dataset back to disk:
(
    df
    .write
    .format("delta")
    .save(output_path)
)
```

However, no matter what I do, the Spark UI shows me exactly 1300 tasks and crashes after 168 tasks with `Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 168 tasks [...] is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize [...]`.

**Further, I tried the following commands:**

- `df.orderBy("contigName", "start", "end").limit(5).toPandas()` works
- `df.orderBy("contigName", "start",    "end").write.format("delta").save(output_path)` fails with `Total size
  of serialized results of 118 tasks (4.0 GB) is bigger than
  spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GB)`
- `df.orderBy("contigName", "start", "end") .persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).limit(5).toPandas()`
  fails as well

**EDIT:
Thanks to @raphael-roth I could tried the following spark config:**

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName('abc')
    .config("spark.local.dir", os.environ.get("TMP"))
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2001")
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4G")
    .getOrCreate()
)
glow.register(spark)
spark
```

However, this still does not affect the number of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

`orderBy` will generate `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` partitions/taks (default=200), no matter how many partitions  the input-DataFrame has. So increasing this number should solve your problem (unfortunately, it cannot be specified in the method call)

Alternatively, think about using something like `repartition(key).sortWithinPartitions(key,attr1,attr2,...)`, this will only generate 1 shuffle instead of 2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Raphael. I tried to increase the shuffle partitions but my program still crashes (see my edit).
My problem is that the data has a specific order (contigName, start, end) which should be enforced. Also, it would be cool if there would not be two different contigNames in the same partition. 
TL;DR: repartition("contigName").sortWithinPartitions(key,attr1,attr2,...) would only generate 22 partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify number of partitions to be created in 2 ways:

1. from code wherever you need (most probably will trigger shuffling across network):

> *df.repartition(800, "hdr_membercode").write.format(table_format).save(full_path,
>   mode=write_mode)*

2. from spark-submit command-line argument:

   *

> --conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=450"

*